# React Native : all text become highlighted instead of pressing the touchable component

Tags: touchableopacity

I am building a app in react native.
i have several buttons with touchable opacity.
it contains text in touchable opacity.
but when I click on touchable opacity,   the text is highlighted , and the touchable opacity is not pressed.
please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or some code at least.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an incomum behavior. Since as you didn't share the code, I would suggest you take a look at the official documentation for check if you did it all right

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity

Some example:

```
const onPress = () => console.log('button pressed');

<TouchableOpacity
  style={{ 
     alignItems: "center", 
     padding: 10, 
     backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD" 
   }}
  onPress={onPress}
>
  <Text>Press Here</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```